# Relation between bilinear symplectic forms and symplectic matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, bilinear-form, symplectic-linear-algebra

**1. Symplectic Forms**

Let $F : \mathbb{K}^{2n} \times \mathbb{K}^{2n} \to \mathbb{K}$ be a bilinear skew-symmetric nondegenerate form (as known as symplectic form).

Then $F(u,v) = u^TAv$ where $A = X^TJ_{2n}X$ where $X$ is invertible and

$$\begin{equation}
J_{2n} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & I_n \\ -I_n & 0 \end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}$$

In this case, $X$ is the change of basis matrix from the standard basis to the *symplectic basis* that $F$ defines on $\mathbb{K}^{2n}$.

**2. Symplectic Matrices**

Separately, we say that a matrix $M$ is symplectic if $M^TJ_{2n}M = J_{2n}$.

***What is the relation between these two concepts?*** They seem connected, but I wasn't able to find the relation between them.

Comment: If $M$ is symplectic, then $M$ preserves the bilinear form $F(u,v) = u^T J v$.  That is, we have $F(Mu,Mv) = F(u,v)$

Comment: Yeah, indeed! Thanks. But is there anything else? I would guess that the matrix $A$ would be symplectic, but it doesn't seem the case...

Comment: No, the matrix $A$ is not generally symplectic.  Maybe this is a better way to put it: $M$ is symplectic if the associated change of basis is such that the standard basis acts as a symplectic basis with respect to $F(u,v) = u^T M^TJMv$.

Comment: I see. Thanks. Please add these comments as an answer, and possibly explain better what you mean by "associated change of basis" and I will accept it.